# Does not work bookmarklet in the theme Tagology

Tags: themes

There is a theme for WordPress - http://cuppster.com/tagology/ I installed it, but bookmarklet does not work! I did everything as written on the website of the topic, but if you click on the link "Tag It", then nothing happens. In what could be the problem? Help please.

Comment: Had you asked/reported this to theme's developer? Questions very specific to functionality of some theme out there rarely get good answers.

Comment: Theme's developer does not answer questions. Not supported, unfortunately. I thought there who can help.

Comment: According to [Github](https://github.com/cuppster/tagology) the author has not made any major theme updates in 2 years.